# How to use bean values in other Java class?

Tags: jsf

I set the values of login form to bean in jsf using expression language and now I want to get those bean values in my other Java program. Please, help me how to get those bean values into other Java program. My code follows:

Login.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<title>sample jsf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
id:<h:inputText value="#{loginbean.id}" />
            <br />
username:<h:inputText value="#{loginbean.username}" />
            <br />
password:<h:inputSecret value="#{loginbean.password}" />
            <br />
            <h:commandButton action="#{insert.getmethod1()}" value="go" />
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

My bean: loginbean.java

```
package com.sensiple.beanvo;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "loginbean")
@SessionScoped
public class loginbean {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;

    }
//beans setting values
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;

    }

}
```

My action class:insert.java

Here I am trying to get values from backing bean and trying to do login authentication,but I an not able to get bean values in to my class.

```
package com.sensiple.impl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.sensiple.beanvo.loginbean;
import com.sensiple.util.RemoteConnection;

@ManagedBean(name = "insert")
@SessionScoped
public class insert {
    public String getmethod1() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
        Connection connection = RemoteConnection.initiateConnection(
                "192.168.3.135", "test", "MBC_User", "root");
        String sql = "select * from login";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (resultSet.next()) 
        {
            loginbean loginbean= new loginbean();
            String id = loginbean.getId();
            System.out.println(id);//i am getting null as i created new bean object,how to get bean vales here
            String user = resultSet.getString("id");
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("id"));
            if ((user == id) && (id != null)) 
            {
            return "Login.xhtml";
            }

        }

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return "s.xhtml";

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 beans for the same page ?

Comment: i am very new to jsf..i dont know how to call a method in other java class from jsf command button..so went for using managed bean which is wrong but i tried to hit java class method ..may i knoe how to call a method in other java class and also how to use bean value in java cladd nethod "getmethod1()"

Comment: Instead of calling getmethod1() directly from the jsf page, call a method in the loginBean and invoke the getmoethod1() from it by passing the required values.

Comment: @Adarsh I suggest moving that comment as answer, then OP may accept it.

Comment: praveenkolla: a Java class **is not** a Java program. A Java program is a class which defines a `public static void main(String[] args)` method and it is called by the JVM and runs in its own JVM instance. What you want/need is to call a method of a class instance from another class instance. Keep in mind that these are two different questions.

Comment: @praveenkolla I have explained in a little more detail to answer what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my response from the comments section to a proper answer.

In JSF, the beans are used to store the state of your web page. The creation and discard tasks are all carried out by the JSF implementation(hence the name 'managed beans'). The beans are stored in the scope map and everytime you use the bean, the JSF implementation looks for the bean in the scope map and if it doesnt find it, creates a new one.

In your program, loginBean is used to store all the values from the login page. Now all the data that has been stored in the bean will exist depending on the scope of your bean(in your case it is session scoped). If you need any method to be invoked from the page using a commandButton, then the method must be defined in a managedBean. In the code that you have provided, you have two managed beans being used in the same web page. One of them stores the page state and the other one holds the method that you are invoking using a commandButton. In your second managedBean, you are trying to access the values stored in the first bean. But you are doing so using the *new* operator. The *new* operator will create a new instance of the bean which wouldn't have any of the values you need.

What you need to do is use one managedBean for your page and invoke a method of the same bean from your page. This would ensure that the same bean instance is in use and you have access to all the stored values. Then based on your need you pass the required values to a simple JAVA class(need not be a managedBean if it is not being used directly in any JSF page) and invoke the required method.